# Scanning for all smart contracts creation on Binance Smart Chain (nodejs + web3)

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js, erc20, bep20

I am trying to scan for smart contracts creation on the BSC but the processing stops after some seconds/minutes. Sometimes it lasts longer. When it stops then the exit code is 0.

Could you know what I'm doing incorrectly in the following code (made with WebStorm).

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const ethers = require('ethers');

const web3 = new Web3('https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443');

const addresses = {
    WBNB: '0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c',
    factory: '0xca143ce32fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fc5350c73',
    router: '0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e',
    recipient: '0xEb519e65aC906F9c670971776851CD7d25848daA'
};

const mnemonic = 'REPLACE';
const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider('wss://bsc-ws-node.nariox.org:443');

const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(mnemonic);
const account2 = wallet.connect(provider);

const factory = new ethers.Contract(
    addresses.factory,
    [
        'event PairCreated(address indexed token0, address indexed token1, address pair, uint)',
        'function getPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external view returns (address pair)'
    ],
    account2
);

console.log('BOT STARTED');
factory.on('PairCreated', async (token0, token1, pairAddress) => {
    console.log("new token pair created on bsc : " + token0 + " " + token1)
})
```